# Does kwargs is passed by value or does unpacking dict copies data?

Tags: python, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, keyword-argument

It is better to illustrate my question by example.
Suppose I have following code:

```
from pprint import pprint

def remove(**kwargs):
    del kwargs['first']


d = {'first': {'x': 10}, 'second': {'a': '1'}}
logger.debug(f"{pprint(d)}")
remove(**d)
logger.debug(f"{pprint(d)}")
```

Output is:

`{'first': {'x': 10}, 'second': {'a': '1'}}`

`{'first': {'x': 10}, 'second': {'a': '1'}}`

That is `'first'` key is still there as if we have passed our dict d **by value**, so any change to it inside the function is not visible for the caller.

I'm expecting that my d is passed *by refference*, that is my dict is modified, I'm expecting to see the following output:

`{'first': {'x': 10}, 'second': {'a': '1'}}`

`{'second': {'a': '1'}}`

Why I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing `d` to the function, you are expanding the values from `d` as named arguments to the function. In the function in question, you are then receiving them as a dictionary again, but if you were to pass values as named arguments or receive values as named arguments, those would not come from or end up in the dictionaries respectively.

e.g. if you could modify the source of `**kwargs`, what would that mean in this case?

```
remove(first={'x': 10}, second={'a': '1'})
```

It wouldn't really make sense.

If you wanted to accomplish the action as implied by the name of your function, you would want to pass a dictionary object as an argument directly; then it would be by reference and modification within the function would work as you are expecting.

```
def remove(dictarg):
    del dictarg['first']
d = {'first': {'x': 10}, 'second': {'a': '1'}}
remove(d)
pprint(d)

>>> {'second': {'a': '1'}}
```

Comment: Thanks. So, what is going on here, my `d` is expanding as named argument of the function and "is detached" from it?